# Akka HTTP using flows with multiple route

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I have a 2 routes as below and I want to map it to Flow so that I can handle multiple request

```
val routes =
      swaggerRoute ~ orderRoute


def init(host: String, port: Int) = {
    val bindingFuture = Http().newServerAt(host, port).bind(routes)
    println(s"Server online at http://localhost:8080/\nPress RETURN to stop...")
    StdIn.readLine() // let it run until user presses return
    bindingFuture
      .flatMap(_.unbind()) // trigger unbinding from the port
      .onComplete(_ => system.terminate()) // and shutdown when done

  }
```

I want to map it to `Flow.mapAsysc(10)` where I can handle multiple request at a time or is there a better way anyone can suggest where I can handle parallel http request

Comment: akka http has many concurrent requests. You can read about it [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/pool-overflow.html) and in many other places. Did you try playing with the configuration? isn't that sufficient for you?

Comment: Did you manage?